# Stored procedure to create a user for mysql5 or mysql 8 depending on the version of mysql

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Basically I am trying to create a stored procedure with an if else statement that checks the mysql server version and based on the version executes a create user with the correct mysql syntax to create the user. we have a mysql 5 and mysql 8 server, and depending on the customers choice we need to create a user on the specific server version, ie mysql 8 or 5

```
USE test;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_user ;

CREATE PROCEDURE add_user()
BEGIN
IF (SELECT VERSION() = '5.7.20-log') THEN
    GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'akoos'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password';
ELSE
    CREATE USER 'akoos'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password';
    GRANT ALL ON test.* TO 'akoos'@'localhost';
END IF ;
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
END
;
CALL add_user() ;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_user ;
```

I tried this but I keep getting syntax errors, all i need to do is create a stored procedure with the correct syntax to create the user and grant privilidges based on the server version its executed on. Ie if its 5 execute the mysql 5 code for creating a user, if its mysql 8 execute the code for creating a user in mysql 8 syntax.  The reason I need this is the wordpress intaller that we use has a mysql script which creates the below code

Mysql 5 code

```
USE test;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_user ;

CREATE PROCEDURE add_user()
BEGIN
GRANT ALL PRIVILEGES ON test.* TO 'akoos'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password';
FLUSH PRIVILEGES;
END
;
CALL add_user() ;
DROP PROCEDURE IF EXISTS add_user ;
```

Mysql 8 needs to use the following syntax to create a user

```
CREATE USER 'akoos'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED BY 'Password';
GRANT ALL ON test.* TO 'akoos'@'localhost';
```

So I want to use an if else statement to create a stored proc based on the db server version used

Comment: `CASE (SELECT LEFT(VERSION(), 2)) WHEN '5.' THEN .. WHEN '8.' THEN .. ELSE .. END;`

Comment: MySQL parses the syntax of the entire procedure before executing anything. So you can't use invalid syntax even if those lines are skipped over by `IF`. If it contains MySQL 8.x syntax, it won't run in 5.x.

Comment: MySQL 5.7 has `CREATE USER`. Why do you think you need to use different syntax?

Answer (score 1):

You should use the `CREATE USER` / `GRANT` method for both versions.

https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/5.7/en/sql-mode.html#sqlmode_no_auto_create_user says:

> It is preferable to create MySQL accounts with CREATE USER rather than GRANT. NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER is deprecated and the default SQL mode includes NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER. Assignments to sql_mode that change the NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER mode state produce a warning, except assignments that set sql_mode to DEFAULT. Expect NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER to be be removed in a future release of MySQL, and its effect to be enabled at all times (and for GRANT not to create accounts any longer).

While it is enforced in MySQL 8.0 that you can't create a user implicitly by granting privileges to them, it's a good idea to let the `NO_AUTO_CREATE_USER` mode be in effect in MySQL 5.x as well. You should create the user explicitly no matter what version you use.

Therefore there's no need for your conditional code.

If you did want to write the conditional code, you can reference a system variable this way:

```
IF (@@version = '5.7.20') THEN
  ...
```

The `-log` suffix may or may not be there. It's the old, old way that MySQL indicated that one of the query logs or the binary log were enabled, before there were other configuration variables for each of the logs. This weird feature of the version variable is no longer used (finally) in MySQL 8.0. But in both versions, there may be another suffix `-debug` that indicates the MySQL Server instance is running a debug build.

So a better to test this variable would be:

```
IF (LEFT(@@version, 2) = '5.') THEN
  ...
```

Then you don't have to worry about version suffixes, or if it's 5.6 versus 5.7, or if it's 5.7.21 versus 5.7.40.